# What is Tizen SDB Application directory error [-16], and how to resolve it?

Tags: c#, .net, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I got interested in making apps for Samsung wearables, and found some info about it. I came across some tutorials and started tinkering with a sample app. I have a physical device (Samsung Gear S3 Frontier SM-R760 Tizen 4.0.0.7 One UI Watch 1.5) and succesfully followed every step to connect my watch. I had some problems, but after some more troubleshooting I finally installed the app. After that I changed some things, started playing with the code, to see what can I do, and to familiarize myself with the options. To my suprise I didn't break anything, it worked, I could install it again and it ran. Then next day when I wanted to install it again from Visual Studio 2019, I couldn't. I checked everything I had problems with earlier, the device is connected (I verified with the Device Manager and the sdb command prompt), my Samsung certificate is valid, the time is right, I tried other WiFi connections, tried with my phone connected/disconnected, tried with Visual Studio, tried directly with `sdb install`. Nothing worked.

If I try Visual Studio 2019 a window pops up with a progress bar saying Installing... and it ends every time at 46%, then comes the Initializing debugger... window, which never stops "loading"

If I try `sdb install` this is the output: ("path" is used instead of the actual path to tpk)

```
C:\Tizen\tools>sdb install "path"\org.tizen.example.XStopWatch-1.0.0.tpk
WARNING: Your data are to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could be read by others.
pushed org.tizen.example.XStopWatch-1.0.0.tpk   100%        649KB           0KB/s
1 file(s) pushed. 0 file(s) skipped.
"path"\org.tizen.example.XStopWatch-1.0.0.tpk   877KB/s (665033 bytes in 0.739s)
path is /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/org.tizen.example.XStopWatch-1.0.0.tpk
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[start] val[install]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[9]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[12]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[15]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[18]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[21]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[25]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[28]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[31]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[34]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[37]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[40]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[43]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[install_percent] val[46]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[error] val[-16]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.XStopWatch] key[end] val[fail]
processing result : Application directory error [-16] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [2012]ms
```

I tried to search for error -16, but with no luck

**Update**

It seems that only this project is faulty, if I try to install something else, that works

Not only that, but if I try to install something with the same name, (or package name I guess), it fails in the same way.

Hope this new info helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solves the problem if you change the Application ID and Package name to something else, not sure if you can install anything from now on with the name and ID of the original app causing this issue

Change:

- Solution name
- csproj name

Change in tizen-manifest.xml

- Application ID
- Package

Comment: Is there any "normal" way to solve this issue? When this issue happen I usually just re-flash the sd card with new tizen, but it doesn't seem to be very efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any other solution anywhere.